# String does not have a member named characters?

Tags: ios, swift

I was trying the **Swift** playground. When I tried the code below, it did not work and told me `'String' does not have a member named 'Characters'`. I expect to print `the number of characters in cafe is 4`. Could you give me any tips? Thanks.

```
var word = "cafe"
print("the number of characters in \(word) is \(word.characters.count)")
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`characters` is a property of `String` in the "new" Swift 2 that comes with Xcode 7 beta.

You are probably using Xcode 6.3.2 with Swift 1.2, then it is

```
print("the number of characters in \(word) is \(count(word))")
```

Two things changed with Swift 2.0 here:

- `String` does no longer conform to `SequenceType`, you have to access
  `.characters` explicitly,
- The global `count()` function has been replaced by a "protocol extension" method `count()`.

Comment: The answer  is good. May I ask what is the best practise(or other typical practises) to get the length of a String in the "new" Swift2. Because the expression like `word.characters.count` seems to be a little bit complicated.Thanks.

Comment: @EricTsui: As far as I know, this *is* how you determine the length. As you can see from the Xcode 7 beta release notes, the `characters` property has been introduced to distinguish the quite general "Unicode extended grapheme cluster view" from the "UTF-16 view" or "UTF-8 view". So `word.utf8.count` would give you the length as a UTF-8 string.

Comment: @Martin R: Thanks for your information which gave the clue to study the `characters` property.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are reading the **Swift 2** tutorial from iBook. That's the new feature. And it will only work in **Xcode 7**.

Answer (score 0):

Use the count characters method:

```
println(the number of characters in \(word) is \(count(word))")
```

With Swift 2:

```
word.characters.count
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, to get the actual characters you can call:

```
let characters = Array(string)
```

You could then simply call:

```
let length = characters.count
```

However, you could also just use the count function if you don't need to iterate the characters or anything in Swift 1.2:

```
let length = count(string)
```

In Swift 2:

```
let length = string.count()
```